# How do I remap `%` with `K` in visual and normal mode in `init.vim` (and vice-versa)?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, neovim

I have the following in my `init.vim`:

```
nnoremap K \%              " Swap K with % in [n]ormal mode
vnoremap K \%              " Swap K with % in [v]isual mode
xnoremap K \%              " Swap K with % in [V]isual mode
nnoremap \% K              " Swap % with K in [n]ormal mode
vnoremap \% K              " Swap % with K in [v]isual mode
xnoremap \% K              " Swap % with K in [V]isual mode
```

All I want is to change the default code block selection which is `%` by default to `K` (<kbd>Shift k</kbd>), but it's not working.

I have escaped the `%` with `\%` and it's not working. I also tried normal `%` and it didn't work either. But whenever I move my cursor on a `{` and then press `K` (<kbd>Shift k</kbd>) then Neovim freezes.

How can I remap this key?

I'm using Neovim.

Comment: I have tested the standard solution and it is working fine. Maybe could you verify launching vim with `vim -i NONE -u NONE` and executing your mapping in the command line (or using the `%so` command) or with `vim --clean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
nnoremap K %
nnoremap % K
vnoremap K %
vnoremap % K
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Vivian works as expected, but I had a very strange issue and it was due to extra space I had after the remapped key and the comment, which wasn't obvious at all.

Meaning that:

```
nnoremap K %              " comment
```

Would have remapped `K` to `%` , but that's not what we want.

That extra whitespace `space` ( ) caused a whole problem for me since I had mapped my `leader` key to `space`. It was hard to debug what I was doing wrong, but it's worth sharing anyway.

I simply moved the comment to live above, and removed the extra whitespace and it got fixed:

```
" comment
nnoremap K %
```

Comment: See `:help map-comments`